# How to implement jquery ui sortable placeholder vertical and horizontal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show jquery ui placeholder both horizontally(top and bottom) and vertically (left or right) as like my sample image. But currently my code shows only top or bottom placeholder. When I place an element, placeholder appears bottom or top position but when i drop element it placed incorrectly.
Here is my sample code

```
            helper: function (event, ui) {
                this.copyHelper = ui.clone().insertAfter(ui);
                return ui.clone();
            },
            placeholder: {
                element: function(currentItem) {
                    return $('<div style="height: 5px; padding: 0; background-color: #F78828;" ></div>');
                },
                update: function(container, p) {$(container.element[0]).addClass("place_here_div");
                    return;
                }
            },
```

[image: When I drag an ui item inside a bootstrap row class div, It shows placeholder at bottom. But I want to show placeholder like this image.]

[image: And when I place a row, want to show placeholder like this.]

Here row column just an example. It may be any kind of element.(div, paragraph, span etc.)

Comment: post fiddle or whole codec !

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zj86s747/
@bRIMOs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer will be useful for you, as it's idea with native HTML5 drag'n'drop. You need to introduce an additional element "row":

```
<div class="root">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-3">component 1</div>
     <div class="col-3">component 2</div>
     <div class="col-3">component 3</div>
     <div class="col-3">component 4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row"><div>
   <div class="row"><div>
</div>
```

And then subscribe on `dragover` event. In the `event`, you will have property `target` and then you can define where you are. Then find the closest drop container (row or root) to target. If in the row - place vertically, otherwise place horizontally.